# Json data modify into new key value pair JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json data that I want to reformat into new key-value pairs. I am using following javascript code to format my json data.

```js
const input = {
    "file1": {
        "function1": {
            "calls": {
                "405:4": {
                "file": "file1",
                "function": "function2"
                },
                "406:4": {
                    "file": "file1",
                    "function": "function3"
                }
            }
        },
        "function2": {
            "calls": {
                "397:7": {
                    "file": "file2",
                    "function": "function1"
                }
            }
        },
        "function3": {
            "calls": null
        },
        "function4": {
            "calls": null
        }
    },
    "file2": {
        "function5": {
            "calls": {
                "43:4": {
                    "file": "file2",
                    "function": "function5"
                }
            }
        },
        "function6": {
            "calls": {
                "32:4": {
                    "file": "file1",
                    "function": "function1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function transformData(data) {
    let  res = [];
    let calls = [];
    Object.entries(data).map(([fileName, fileObject]) => {
        Object.entries(fileObject).map(([functionName, functionObject]) => {
            Object.entries(functionObject).map(([functionKey, functionValue]) => {
                if(functionKey === "calls") {
                    Object.entries(functionValue).map(([callKey, callObject]) => {
                        calls = [...calls, callObject['file']+"."+callObject['function']]
                    });
                } 
            });
            res = [...res,{"name": fileName+"."+functionName, "import": calls}]  
        });
    });
    return res;
}
const sanitize = (obj) => {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
        return (value === null ? undefined : value);
    }));
};
const data = sanitize(input)
const result = transformData(data);
console.log(result)
```

My expected json data is following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "file1.function1",
    "imports": [
      "file1.function2",
      "file1.function3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "file1.function2",
    "imports": [
      "file2.function1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "file1.function3",
    "imports": []
  },
  {
    "name": "file1.function4",
    "imports": []
  },
  {
    "name": "file2.function5",
    "imports": [
      "file2.function5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "file2.function6",
    "imports": [
      "file1.function1"
    ]
  }
]
```

My output is not correct. Though its giving right amount of main array with name and imports keys but the import array is wrong.

Can someone please help me. I think i'm not returning it in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake that you're doing is, you're assigning the same `calls` array to `import` each time and not clearing the past elements on subsequent iterations. Replace with this code for obtaining the expected outcome.

```js
function transformData(data) {
    let res = [];
    Object.entries(data).map(([fileName, fileObject]) => {
        Object.entries(fileObject).map(([functionName, functionObject]) => {
            let calls = []; // Notice this line. I'm creating new array for every iteration. Another way is to clear the array before proceeding.
            Object.entries(functionObject).map(([functionKey, functionValue]) => {
                if(functionKey === "calls") {
                    Object.entries(functionValue).map(([callKey, callObject]) => {
                        calls = [...calls, callObject['file']+"."+callObject['function']]
                    });
                } 
            });
            res = [...res,{"name": fileName+"."+functionName, "import": calls}]  
        });
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Oh. Okay! I didn't notice that!
Thank you so much.